# To what degree should the oldness of my phone affect my tethering speed?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, tethering

I have an iPhone 4s on Verizon that I am using to tether with Bluetooth. [TestMy.net](http://testmy.net) indicated a throughput of about 200kbps, which it suggests is 2% of the typical throughput it sees from Verizon.

It occurs to me just now that it could be comparing this to FiOS speed instead of other tethered network clients, but my question is: would I expect to see radically different connection speeds if I was using an iPhone 5s instead of the 4s? Is Bluetooth less capable than wi-fi tethering?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is slower than WiFi but it conserves battery power.

BT are capable up to 2 Mbps, which equals 240 KB/s, sounds like you are right on the target.

<sub>Kilobytes per second (KBps) and Megabits per second (Mbps)</sub>

[Source](http://www.macworld.com/article/1159258/bluetooth_tethering.html):

> Bluetooth 2.1+EDR, the flavor built into all iOS devices, has a raw
>   rate of 3 Mbps and a net throughput that’s just a bit over 2 Mbps.
>   That’s fine on Verizon’s 3G network, where average speeds never top 2
>   Mbps.

Comment: Well, not quite: I did really mean 200 kbps -- little b bits. This does seem to vary quite greatly in different areas, even all with good service -- I've also tested at 1.2 Mbps down/361 Kbps up. So, not great -- 11% of average.

Comment: But indeed, the "average" of 8.1 Mbps is far beyond the capability of Bluetooth. So I should take that into consideration.

Comment: Oh, but the iPhone 4s uses Bluetooth 4.0, not 2.1+EDR.

Comment: If you have 200 k bits per second that would be very slow = 1.6 k bites per second. A computer needs 8 bit to form a bite and that is a minimum to create a letter/symbol. The upload speed is regulated by the authorities and maxed out at 400.

Comment: I'm well aware of that -- hence my issue. My tethering internet feels like I'm on four dial-up lines bundled together sometimes.

Comment: Since you have the BT 4 it is capable of up to 20Mbps, well beyond what Verizon is offering you.